# ML Models that are null invariate

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science

My company's hosting a friendly data science competition based off of the PhysioNet challenge [here](https://www.physionet.org/content/challenge-2019/1.0.0/)

But with a much simpler scoring system and unfortunately no prize XD Some quick background, I'm not a data science/machine learning expert by any means. I've done some simple projects messing around with standard library models like kNN, regression, etc. And I've worked with data with missing values, but in those cases it wasn't 95+% and you could safely impute using mean or median.

A quick overview of the problem, so much of the data is missing because the values they measure are test results, and due to costs tests are taken infrequently and only when ordered for specific reasons (most likely because a physician suspects something's wrong with the patient). I've read a bunch of the papers from the physionet challenge [submissions](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PPQY0SdguwCx_CxbR1BYlkh0dwpINlhEFxejc10xwgM/edit) and have come up with a few points. I've chosen features based on those used to identify sepsis and then use PCA to see if any of them are highly correlated to other sparse features that I could drop. Missing values are imputed with foward-fill if possible, but if there's no previous value they remain NaN. For features that are decently populated, I can fill missing values with the mean or median depending on the shape of the data.

Also I'm working in python, if that makes a difference for modules and such.

But that's where I hit a bit of a problem. There's still a lot of null values left and imputing doesn't make sense (if you have 98% null, imputing with the mean would introduce tremendous bias) but discarding them also seems bad. For example, a patient who stayed for a very short time and left without getting any tests taken because they had a quick recovery would be missing all their test values. So, ironically, the lack of data actually tells you something in some cases.

I was trying to do some research on what models can handle null values and so far the internet has given me Regression Trees and Gradient Boosting models, both of which I've never used so I don't know how well they work with missing values. Also, I've read some conflicting information that some of them actually just use mean imputation under the hood to fill in the values? (though I might be wrong since, again, I don't have any first hand experience with these models. But for example in [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/98953/why-doesnt-random-forest-handle-missing-values-in-predictors/186264#186264) post).

So **tl;dr**, if your dataset has null values you don't want to throw out, what are some models that would handle that well? Or for regression trees and gradient boosting models, how do they handle null values? It seems like they replace them in some cases, but there's a lot of different sources conflicting on how. The most popular model I seem to be running into is XGBoost which also does well with structured data (which this is)

EDIT: Some relevant analysis - the data is highly skewed. There's like 400+K entries and 90% of them are non-sepsis. Also the fields with high sparsity are like 90-99% null, which is why imputing with the mean or median doesn't make sense to me. Forward-filling lowers that number by quite a bit but there's still a significant amount. There's also cases where a patient will have 100% null values for a field because they never had a test requested (so there's no way to impute even if you wanted to)

Comment: One common tactic is to replace null / NaN values with median or mean values from the training set.

Comment: I just edited it to clarify since I realized I'd left it out, but these are fields where 90-99% of the values are null. The dataset is 400+K entries, imputing with mean or median would introduce a LOT of bias and probably make things worse

Comment: This is a great question, however, it's more suitable for stats.stackexchange.com since it's not specifically about programming. Working with data for which many or most items are missing is a difficult, important topic. The right thing to do is going to depend on assumptions about why the data are missing, which is going to be especially important in a medical context, and therefore it is impossible to devise a one-size-fits-all solution, so no off-the-shelf package can handle this. If I were going to work on this, I would treat it as a problem in Bayesian inference. Good luck and have fun.

Comment: This is likely off topic for Stack Overflow. See: [help/on-topic]. You can find a discussion on relevant Stack Exchange sites [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130524).